# assigning row names to column names based on highest percentage

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

```
voyages =(
VIC0016,
VIC0016,
VIC0016,
VIC0016,
VIC0016,
VIC0016,
Truck,
VIC0016,
VIC0016,
VIC0016,
JUL0983,
BB11356,
VIC0022,
VIC0022,
ISK1981,
ISK1981,
ISK1981,
ISK1981,
ISK1981,
ISK1981,
ISK1981,
ISK1981,
ISK1981,
ISK1981,
ISK1981,
ISK1981)

clusters = (5,
5,
5,
4,
4,
4,
1,
3,
4,
3,
5,
2,
4,
5,
6,
6,
6,
6,
6,
6,
6,
6,
6,
6,
6,
6)

>calculate.confusion <- function(voyages, clusters)  
{
  d <- data.frame(voyages, clusters)  
  td <- as.data.frame(table(d))  
  # convert the raw counts into percentage of each voyage number  
  pc <- matrix(ncol=max(clusters),nrow=0)  
  for (i in 1:11) # 11 different voyage numbers  
  {  
    total <- sum(td[td$voyages==td$voyages[i],3])   
    #,3 is the third column, showing the frequencies  
    pc <- rbind(pc, td[td$voyages==td$voyages[i],3]/total)  
  }   
  rownames(pc) <- td[1:11,1]  
  colnames(pc)<-1:11  
  return(pc)  
}
```

Having the above data frame (numbers are percentages), how can I replace the column names [1:11] by the names of the rows, in such a way that:

- within the row, the column having the highest percentage in that row is named after that row
- every row name is used once

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, see the link above on how to give a reproducible example.

Comment: the data frame is a confusion matrix after k means clustering, transformed in percentages

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(3,2,1), c = c(2,3,1))
colnames(df)
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {colnames(df)[df[i, ] == max(df[i, ])] <- rownames(df)[i]}
colnames(df)
# [1] "3" "1" "2"
```

Comment: Dear, when I try this, not al the voyages numbers are used and some are used twice. Besides, the column containing the highest percentage is not always given the name of that voyage. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: There is always a way.. Please try to ask a more specific question for a more specific answer (providing a standalone running example). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example